# Pojo with unnamed list

Tags: android, rest, pojo

I have a link to JSON list and i want to load it in my RecycleView(android). I have done same lists, but them often have a names(List results  - example).
I have tried to make POJO with list with reffers, but it's not work, although massive of data is loading - in logs.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TextView tvName;
  Call<ObjectsListResponse> call;
  private final OAuthService service = RestApi.createService(OAuthService.class);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.item);
    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);

    call = service.getListCities();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ObjectsListResponse>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ObjectsListResponse> call, Response<ObjectsListResponse> response){
            ObjectsListResponse objectListResponse = response.body();
            tvName.setText(objectListResponse.getAny().get(0).getName());

        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <ObjectsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            if(call.isCanceled()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}`

```
public class ObjectsListResponse {
@SerializedName("")
List<ObjectResponse> any;

public List <ObjectResponse> getAny() {
    return any;
}
```

}

```
public class ObjectResponse {
@SerializedName("_entityName")
private String entityName;
@SerializedName("_instanceName")
private String instanceName;
@SerializedName("id")
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("version")
private String version;

public String getEntityName() {
    return entityName;
}

public String getInstanceName() {
    return instanceName;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String  getVersion() {
    return version;
}
```

}

**JSON list without name**

[image: JSON list without name]

**JSON List with Images**

[image: JSON List with Images]

Comment: [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Use this site to create POJO classes for your.

Comment: I have used it already, no deference. It created POJO class for one object, but I need pojo for list, each hasn't a name,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your response is a JSON array at the top level, which means that there *is no* top-level response object. You just have a list of "inner" response objects.

So you need to delete this class altogether:

> ```
> public class ObjectsListResponse {
>
>     @SerializedName("")
>     List<ObjectResponse> any;
>
>     public List <ObjectResponse> getAny() {
>         return any;
>     }
> }
> ```

And change your `Call` object to be a `Call<List>` instead. So replace this:

> ```
> Call<ObjectsListResponse> call;
> ```

and

> ```
> call.enqueue(new Callback<ObjectsListResponse>(){
>     @Override
>     public void onResponse(Call<ObjectsListResponse> call, Response<ObjectsListResponse> response){
>         ...
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onFailure(Call<ObjectsListResponse> call, Throwable t) {
>         ...
>     }
> });
> ```

with this:

```
Call<List<ObjectResponse>> call;
```

and this

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ObjectsListResponse>(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ObjectResponse>> call, Response<List<ObjectResponse>> response){
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ObjectResponse>> call, Throwable t) {
        ...
    }
});
```